# Vim issue with running specs in Ruby/Rspec

Tags: vim

I am using Vim as my main editors for a few days now.
Using http://www.github.com/astrails/dotvim as the base of my installation.

The problem I am having is that when I run the specs, the result of the specs is not delayed on the screen and I can't see what is going on.

to further explain this, I have a video to demo the situation:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gUB48XwNq0M&feature=plcp

I need to hide vim with CTRL+Z and then fg to show it again, that's obviously not good.

Would love help on this

** Edit **

I posted about the problem in more detail here:
http://avi.io/blog/2012/08/05/problem-with-running-spec-in-vim/

Answer (score 1):

I would first check if this is the same behavior for any shell command you run, or just when you run spec files.
*E.g.* how does a simple run of *'ls'* from within VIM behave?

```
:!ls
```

If the above waits for '*Enter*', I would guess that you have a trailing space (or similar) in the mapping that runs your spec.
For example, adding this line to your .*vimrc* will map *Leader-l* to the 'ls' command and will prompt for '*Enter*'.

```
nmap <leader>l :!ls<cr>
```

However if you add the same line with a **trailing space at the end**, it will exit the console immediately:

```
nmap <leader>l :!ls<cr>
```

So I would check the mapping you use to run the specs.

Answer (score 0):

This might have something to do with `:help more`, but I think the best solution for this sort of thing is a combination of [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) and [turbux.vim](https://github.com/jgdavey/vim-turbux/). See the video [here](http://vimeo.com/34879707).